# grep output all capture groups, evening without a match

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk

I am writing a bash script and I'm using grep with a regular expression for some DNS records, and I have 4 capture groups, **the second one is optional**.

Is it possible to get these output so that there will **always** be five groups, and they are in the same order each time.

Regex I'm using in for `grep -Eo`

```
^([a-z0-9@\-\.\*]+?)\s+(?:([0-9]*)\s)?([A-Z]*)\s*(.*)$
```

Content to match:

```
www    43200 A 1.2.3.4
t        CNAME s.test.com.
blog             A 4.3.2.1
@                   MX 20 cluster3a.eu.messagelabs.com.
@                   TXT ( "some text" )
```

When fed in to something like `awk`, I'd like the output for each line to be as follows

```
$1 = www , $2 = 43200 , $3 = A , $4 = 1.2.3.4
$1 = t , $2 = , $3 = CNAME , $4 = s.test.com.
$1 = @ , $2 = , $3 = MX , $4 = MX 20 cluster3a.eu.messagelabs.com.
$1 = @ , $2 = , $3 = TXT , $4 = ( "some text" )
```

Just for clarity, i would like **all** groups to be output **in order**.

Tearing my hair out on this one. All help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be using a perl-style regex, which won't work with `grep -E` (you need `grep -P`, which is non-standard but works with gnu grep), and which also won't normally work with `awk`. Fortunately, you don't need any of the extensions.

Here's a simple regular expression which will work, in awk format, with exactly four captures:

```
/^([a-z0-9*@.-]+)[[:blank:]]+([0-9]*)[[:blank:]]*([A-Z]+)[[:blank:]]*(.*)/
```

You can use it as follows (but only with Gnu awk: the three-argument version of `match` is a Gnu extension):

```
awk '{match($0,
            /^([a-z0-9*@.-]+)[[:blank:]]+([0-9]*)[[:blank:]]*([A-Z]+)[[:blank:]]*(.*)/,
            field);
      print "<" field[1] "> <" field[2] "> <" field[3] "> <" field[4] ">";
     }' \
<<<'www    43200 A 1.2.3.4
t        CNAME s.test.com.
blog             A 4.3.2.1
@                   MX 20 cluster3a.eu.messagelabs.com.
@                   TXT ( "some text" )'
```

Output:

```
<www> <43200> <A> <1.2.3.4>
<t> <> <CNAME> <s.test.com.>
<blog> <> <A> <4.3.2.1>
<@> <> <MX> <20 cluster3a.eu.messagelabs.com.>
<@> <> <TXT> <( "some text" )>
```

However, it might well be simpler to use awk's own line splitting facility:

```
awk '{  if ($2~/^[[:digit:]]+$/) { ttl=$2; type=$3; arg=4; }
       else                     { ttl=0;  type=$2; arg=3; }
       name=$1
       args=$arg
       for (++arg;arg<=NF;++arg) args=args " " $arg                   
       # ...
     }'
```

Comment: Getting ``awk: syntax error at source line 2``. Usin your first example. I'm on a mac and have installed homebrew grep and awk :-(

Comment: @twilson yeah, match with three arguments requires gnu awk. Sorry. Other awks don't provide a way to extract captures. The second script works with original-awk.

Comment: Okay, how exactly would I use that second script, I'm struggling to get that to produce output either. I'm sure I'm probably missing something simple. My brain hurts, it's been a very long day :-P

Comment: Add what you want at the comment. The fields are called name, ttl, type, args. ttl is 0  if it wasnt present but you can change that in the else statement.

Comment: Cheers @rici. That did the job perfectly.